# Applying modifiers of MPFB model before exporting to gltf

Tags: modeling, modifiers, export, shape-keys, gltf

I have a model created with MPFB (free and open source human character generator for blender).
When I tried to apply modifiers I got an error: Modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape key.

Then I tried to use Skeeper to apply modifiers with shape keys and the model has broken.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This Q&A site can only answer about problems with Blender and its built-in addons. Both the programs/addons you mention are third-party ones and therefore you'll have to ask the authors directly.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "operations" panel, there is a sub-panel for basemesh and a button "bake all shape keys". This is probably what you are looking for.

Another alternative is to use a proxy mesh (found under apply assets and proxymeshes) and delete the base mesh once you've finished modeling.

As a side-note: If you need support for MPFB, there is an issue tracker where you can post support requests. It is here: https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mpfb2/issues

Comment: Thank you. After your reply I`ve managed to solve my problem with that script: import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    if not hasattr(ob.data, "shape_keys"):
        continue
    ob.shape_key_add(name='CombinedKeys', from_mix=True)
    if ob.data.shape_keys:
        for shapeKey in ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
            ob.shape_key_remove(shapeKey)